# MVC3 tools/Add-ins/Addons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a C# (WinForms) developer and I'm now getting into MVC3. I want to start right away with the right tools. I keep asking myself why I started C# without ReSharper. I don't want to program without the proper tools anymore.

I've searched a lot on Google, but I've found no specific tool/productivity add-ons for MVC3. Are the any? Do you use any? Is there any use/need for a third party tool in MVC3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex, especially the filters and action results.

If you want to get into DI/IoC (since MVC3 is friendly to that), check out some of my favorite tools -- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) or [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Basically the only tools we use in our development is included in the MVC 3.0 installer.  The Razor View Engine, other than that is nothing.  I mean when you got MVC, you got what you need for productivity and maintainability.  ReSharper you said? [No thanks!](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/01/designed-by-programmers.html) :)

http://www.asp.net/mvc

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215693

Comment: Not sure if the ReSharper thing is meant as a joke, and if it is I apologize, but that's downright stupid. R# is the single most productive tool out there for .Net developers (or CodeRush if that's your cup of tea). Yes, there's lots of dialogs and tidbits of info onscreen, but that's a GOOD thing...

Comment: @BFree, no worries, the smile tells it.

Comment: @BFree - I don't understand the picture? Is he saying he doesn't like R# because the install image demonstrates a lot of functionality and he's overwhelmed by it?

Comment: @Phill: That's how I interpreted the picture... That there was somehow too much clutter in the IDE once R# was installed....

Comment: @Phill, What don't you ask the author of the blog, i assume he will be happy to throw you heaps of things related to your question.  I mean its quite wrong to have speculation, what do you think? Let me know how it goes. ;)

Comment: @Peyton - Ahh It's Ivan's blog from Mind Scape. Haha. No I don't think it's wrong to have speculation, my introduction to R# was watching someone use it, and there was no clutter on the screen, so I always viewed the installer and demonstrating the functionality. That's why I didn't understand what the picture was about.

Comment: @Phill, Haha, yes he is.  I thought you've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a CRUD application using MVC then [MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) will help you a lot. You can customize the templates and then generate controllers and views very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

perosnally I use:

- [T4MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/T4MVC/)
- [MefContrib.MVC3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MefContrib.MVC3/)
- [Moq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MOQ)
- [MvcRouteUnitTester](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRouteUnitTester/)
- [StronglyTypedViews](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StronglyTypedViews/)
- [AttributeRouting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/)